# Limit href attributes in TimyMCE links

Tags: node.js, tinymce

I have created an app in nodeJS using TinyMCE for rich text user input.  How do I limit  attribute so that users can only set up links to select domains?  For instance only www.youtube.com, and that way they can't put links to dangerous websites.

I have no idea where to begin. This is most likely very easy but I can't find it anywhere in the docs